# What does Putin say in Russian that is translated "lead you to such consequences that you have never faced in your history"

Tags: перевод

In [this short video](https://youtu.be/rJq6u2ryG68?t=50) (starting at 0:50 point) Putin warns that interference with his "special operation" would `lead you to such consequences that you have never faced in your history`.

What is the Russian words he uses to say the "lead you to such consequences that you have never faced in your history" in written (cyrillic) form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...приведет вас к таким последствиям, с которыми вы в своей истории еще никогда не сталкивались.